# Swift - If user enters from 1 to 100 then display random message

Tags: swift, random, type-conversion

I have an array of random messages, and I want to display one of those messages as output using label and only if the user enters between 1 to 100, so when user enters between 1 to 100 and presses the button the label should generate one of those random messages.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!


let arrayMessages = ["message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4", "Message 5"]
let numberRange = 1...100



@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayMessages.count)))
    let output = arrayMessages[random]

    if (inputTextField.text == numberRange){
        outputLabel.text = output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to convert the entered text into an `Int`. Then you need to see if the range contains that number.

```
@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let num = Int(inputTextField.text!), numberRange.contains(num) {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayMessages.count)))
        let output = arrayMessages[random]
        outputLabel.text = output
    } else {
        // Not a valid number or the number isn't in range
    }
}
```

Also note that there's no reason to get the random message unless you actually need it.

Comment: Awesome, I understand it better now, Thanks again rmaddy :). I know the random messages isn't really realistic/useful but I just wanted to know how that would work so its purely educational. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of doing a number range, you can see if the text is greater than or equal to one and less than or equal to 100.

```
@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!


let arrayMessages = ["message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4", "Message 5"]

@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayMessages.count)))
    let output = arrayMessages[random]


    if (Double(inputTextField.text!) >= 1 && Double(inputTextField.text!) <= 100){
        outputLabel.text = output
    } else {
       // Number is less than 1 or greater than 100
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile since `Double(someString)` returns an optional and you can't use the `>=` or the `<=` operators with an optional. You also needlessly convert the text twice. And you should the case of the user entering text that isn't a number.